# Ubuntu login loops and never works

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

I messed something up with `$PATH` now whenever I login it restarts and shows login screen and when I login using `ctrl+alt+f3` and try to change something it says command sudo is available in `/bin/sudo` I read like 30 posts but none of solutions worked

Comment: When you login on C+A+F3 what does your $PATH look like? You might just get away with setting the path to /bin/ or running /bin/sudo directly

Comment: When I echo $PATH it says /home/username/bin:/home/username/.local/bin:'/home/username/bin:'

Comment: It's pretty long but at the end it's path to java-8-oracle/jre/bin for some reason

Comment: My $PATH contains /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin  Apart from the snap and games you might want to add those while you correct your .bashrc

Comment: I changed to yours and commands works but anyway can't login